# Latin in the European Parliament

Tags: modern-life

I vaguely remember that once the following happened in the European Parliament: One member of the parliament delivered a speech in Latin, and afterwards another member stood up and answered the speech in Latin, too.

I want to know when this event happened and who were the involved speakers?

Comment: Do you have at least a vague idea about when this happened? I remember a bishop from East Europe doing something similar in a Synod, some 6-8 years ago I think. Probably even there, most bishops attending didn't understand.

Comment: I am not sure, but when I remember right the answerer was Otto von Habsburg (CSU), pinning down the time interval to 1979–1999.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you refer to the event that involved the speakers **Mario Capanna** and **Otto von Habsburg**. Capanna was an extreme left-wing Italian member, who made a speech in Latin in the session of **November 13th, 1979**. It seems that one of the few to understand his speech was the Euro MP Otto von Habsburg, a direct descendant of the Royal House of the Austro-Hungarian Empire, and an elected member for the right-wing Catholic Party (CSU) in Bavaria.

The speech given by Mario Capanna can be found in [this link](https://www.facebook.com/174247906107064/posts/lintervento-in-latino-di-mario-capanna-al-parlamento-europeoin-giorni-in-cui-son/226582074206980/). Here is a copy&paste of it:

> Amplissimi collegae, quid re vera significant regulae costitutionisque emendationes, quas Nord, vir ex amplissimis, proposuit? Huius relationis causae minimum quinque sunt.
>
> Primum: exceptione statim facta ante diem quartum Idus Iunias, cum ita numerus minimus constitutus est, ut factiones quae quaternas suffragiorum centesimas superassent – quod in Gallia Germaniaque factum esse vidimus – nullum legatum electum habere potuerint, nunc altera exceptio, ad eos qui priorem effugerunt
>   amovendos, proponitur: numerus enim minimus legatorum, qui ad factionem constituendam postulantur, id est unus et viginti, idem valet atque quinae
>   centesimae pro universis decem et quadringentis legatis.
>
> Alterum: numerus minimus ad unum et viginti augetur, at non, exempli gratia, ad quinque et viginti, ut simul et factio cuius socius sum evertatur, et legatorum Gollistarum factio maneat, qui viginti duo tantum sunt.
>
> Tertium: legatorum autem conventus, nulli parti adstrictus, quem nuper arte, ne dicam fraude, viri medium quiddam tenentes creari iusserunt, nullam decernendi habet potestatem, quippe qui ne conciliis quidem Praefecturae, quibus auctis Publicum Consilium utitur, interesse suffragium ferens possit.
>
> Quartum: nemo profecto est qui non videat nos ita una cum fascistis legatis adesse cogi et commune cum iisdem minimum illud tempus dicendi habere.
>
> Quintum: ex quo consequitur – quod omnibus gravissima videbitur iniuria – ut velut duo legatorum genera constituantur, optimum alterum, alterum deterius, quibus non
>   aeque facultas patet sententiam proponendi.
>
> Satis superque – quod mihi saltem videtur – est, ut horreat quicumque liber nec coactus ius exerceat, horreat praecipue quicumque civium intellegat, quid re vera non modo in Europaeorum Publico Consilio, quod nuper omnium suffragio creatum est, sed etiam ex eodem – ut ita dicam – occulte subrepere incipiat.
>
> Id maximum: non est quidem Europaeorum Publicum Consilium inutile quiddam, quod publicis rebus administrandis addatur, quo, quasi in vas quoddam, bona malaque studia confluant eorum, qui novem res publicas regunt. Quin etiam longe aliud est,
>   multoque maius.
>
> Publicum enim Europaeorum Consilium, ubi, post Iunii mensis suffragia, haud
>   dubie qui quiddam medium tenent plurimum valent, nihil aliud est – mea sententia
>   – nisi magna quaedam negotiis explendis societas, quam de industria quidam
>   instituerunt, ut, si plane componere nequirent, quodam modo saltem conciliarent
>   necessitates contrarias saepe oppositasque eorum qui, in novem illis congregatis civitatibus, vel divitiis, vel fabricis, vel mercaturis, imperium exercent.
>
> Ne quem fallat quod de inanibus rebus ii qui in Consilio sunt leviter ac vane loquuntur; nam de gravibus rebus omnia, velut musicae artis magister quidam, regit et componit Germaniae ad Occidentem versae legatus, qui, Gallicis vestibus indutus,
>   Italicis calceamentis – Populari, quae dicitur, Christianaque parte iuvante –
>   utitur, nec Britannorum tunicas sumere spernit.
>
> Quibus ex rebus nonnulla adhuc obscura in lucem veniunt.Ita enim plane intelligitur, curnam huic Consilio mulier praesit, quae, nisi quattuor isti Italorum fascistae legati suffragium tulissent, ad hanc dignitatem non pervenisset; curnam Collegium rerum naturae viribus perspiciendis adhibendisque creatum statuerit (quae omnia ego, huius Collegii particeps, ipsis vidi oculis) ut magis magisque congregatarum civitatum carbo effoderetur, itaque praecipue Germanis, Britannis, Gallis faveretur, minime autem Italis, quibus hic carbo multo pluris stat quam ut emere possint; curnam Collegium immutato vultu consilium accipiat centum quinquaginta fluxus ex atomis profecti diribitoria in posteros decem annos exstruendi; curnam, praeter verba, ne digitum quidem porrigat noves opes, quae etiam atque etiam renovari possint, modo et ratione promovendi causa.
>
> Longius quidem est omnia enumerare. Tamen quod diximus satis superque est, ut demonstretur vera causa,cur factionem nostram petant qui eam delendam esse censeant; nam hoc Publicum Consilium, quippe quod Europenses divitias ad paucos redactas administrare atque tueri susceperit, graviter profecto fert decem fere legatos esse, qui statutum atque deliberatum habeant una acerrime propugnare ad eos quoque defendendos, qui vetiti sunt Publico Europaeorum Consilio interesse, atque ad utilitatem tuendam Europensium opificum iuvenumque.
>
> Nam, cum hoc Publicum Consilium commodis utilitatique studeat eorum qui divitias sibi congesserunt, facere non potest quin ipsum, in primis apud se,civium libertatem coerceat.
>
> His de causis pro populari ratione, quae in hoc Consilio coercetur atque
>   conculcatur, omnibus viribus contendimus.

The reply given by Otto von Habsburg can be found on page 36 of [this link](http://www.pro-lingua-latina.de/index_htm_files/Otto_v_Habsburg.pdf):

> Oratiuncula qua Otto von Habsburg respondit honorabili collegae suo Capannae:
>
> Magno mihi gaudio fuit, quod in sententia tua referenda usus es lingua vere Europaea et matre quodammodo omnium nostrum, qua diutius carere in hoc egregio concilio vix possumus. Ita fit, ut, qui in eis, quae dixisti nullo modo assentiri tibi, quem tamen valde gratulum tibi censeam, quod ausus es loqui Latine, quod quam utile sit, nonnullis nostrae aetatis hominibus non liquet propter egestatem
>   cultus atque humanitatis. Ego contra perstandum esse in isto proposito Latinitatis provehendae censeo, praecipue in scholis nostris, quod humaniores nos reddet et sapientiores magisque conciliabit inter se tot gentes, tot nationes omni respectu diversas, beneficio latinitatis tamen coniunctissimas.
>   Cui proposito invigilare, cui operam nostram impendere non pigebit; quod ad effectum perducere nostri non est, sed 'maneat nostros ea cura nepotes'.

Comment: Sir, your good self has forgotten to translate this. If you swear at me, in Latin, it will be forgiven.

Comment: @tony A [quel link](https://www.facebook.com/174247906107064/posts/lintervento-in-latino-di-mario-capanna-al-parlamento-europeoin-giorni-in-cui-son/226582074206980/) c'è una traduzione italiana. If you want it in English, you might paste the Italian into Google Translate, which does a better job with Italian than with Latin (or possibly click the "See Translation" button on the Facebook page).

Comment: @Ben Kovitz: Thank you. Was having a little joke with Mitomino; but, keep forgetting that (English) humour does not travel, hope he wasn't offended, in some way. Have a good weekend.